# Accept / Decline an event invitation (RSVP) with a message using Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a Facebook application that can [Accept / Decline events invitations](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/). But the documentation doesn't specify if it's possible to give a reason (message) with the RSVP.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hmmm, +1....I can't find such a field myself, good question

Comment: Well, after a lot of test, I can only use https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/declined attending etc   THEN I can post on event's wall. But it seems that only a few of Post object properties are working (no Actions fields, Caption, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that you must

1. [Accept](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/attending) / [Maybe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/maybe) or [Decline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/declined) to RSVP
2. .then() you can [POST your message to event feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/feed)

Note than you can only post text or link to the feed. Custom stories or other type of message body cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

The web interface uses `wall_note` as the input field name and since the other input field names match with the API this would be the logical parameter name. It does not work in my testing though.

I couldn't find any open feature requests for it either: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/